# Como manipulo uma data em um EditText para somar 1 dia?

Tags: android, sqlite, sql-update, calendar

Recebo em um EditText uma data e preciso que ao apertar o botão de renovação essa data seja acrescida de 1 dia.

```
package br.edu.unp.bibliotecavirtual.view;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import br.edu.unp.bibliotecavirtual.R;
import br.edu.unp.bibliotecavirtual.config.CustomAdapterLivro;
import br.edu.unp.bibliotecavirtual.config.DatabaseHelper;
import br.edu.unp.bibliotecavirtual.model.RenovacaoModelo;

public class ListarEmprestimosActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private EditText empTitulo, empDataemp, empDatadevol; //, 
etRegistroLivro;
private Button btnRenovado, btnDevolvido;
private RenovacaoModelo renovacaoModelo;
//private View view;
// private ListView listView;
private ArrayList<RenovacaoModelo> renovacaoModeloArrayList;
private CustomAdapterLivro customAdapterlivro;
private DatabaseHelper databaseHelper;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_renovates_give_back);
    Intent intent = getIntent();

    renovacaoModelo = (RenovacaoModelo) 
  intent.getSerializableExtra("user");
    databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);

//RESGATA VALORES PARA OS TEXTVIEW VINDOS DOS GETTER E SETTERS e dos ArrayLists
```

//exibe no textview

```
    empTitulo = findViewById(R.id.empTitulo);
    empDataemp = findViewById(R.id.empDataemp);
    empDatadevol = findViewById(R.id.empDatadevol);

    empTitulo.setText(renovacaoModelo.getTitulo());
    empDataemp.setText(renovacaoModelo.getDataemp());
    empDatadevol.setText(renovacaoModelo.getDatadevol());


  // BOTOES DE AÇÃO DO FORMULÁRIO
    btnRenovado = findViewById(R.id.btnRenovado);
    btnDevolvido = findViewById(R.id.btnDevolvido);

  // função dos botoes renovar entregar
    btnRenovado.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //, etRegistro.getText().toString()
            databaseHelper.renovaLivro(renovacaoModelo.getId(),
                    empTitulo.getText().toString(), 
 empDataemp.getText().toString(), empDatadevol.getText().toString());// , 
 etRegistroLivro.getText().toString());
            Toast.makeText(ListarEmprestimosActivity.this, "Livro 
 Renovado com Sucesso!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 // MainActivity = tela principal
            Intent intent = new Intent(ListarEmprestimosActivity.this, 
 MainActivity.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | 
 Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    btnDevolvido.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
 //renovacaoModelo
            databaseHelper.devolverLivro(renovacaoModelo.getId());
            Toast.makeText(ListarEmprestimosActivity.this, "Livro 
 Devolvido com Sucesso!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent intent = new Intent(ListarEmprestimosActivity.this, 
 MainActivity.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | 
 Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });


}
}
```

a classe com a função que fará o update da base de dados:

```
 public int renovaLivro(int id, String titulo, String dataempre, String 
 datadevol) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        //Criando valores do content
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_EMP_ID, id);
        values.put(KEY_TITULOEMPRE, titulo);
        values.put(KEY_DATAATUAL, dataempre);
        values.put(KEY_DATADEVOLUCAO, datadevol); // adiciona mais 10 
dias na data final
//--->   //
       return  db.update(TABLE_EMPRESTIMO, values, KEY_EMP_ID + " = ?",
                  new String[]{String.valueOf(id)});
    }
// fim função emprestimo
```

[image: Renovação e Devolução]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá,

Tente da seguinte forma, obtenha o valor do seu `EditText` que virá na forma de uma `String`. Depois transformamos essa `String` num objeto do tipo `Date`

```
String dateValue = seuEditText.getText().
   .toString()
   .trim();

SimpleDateFormat ft = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
Date date = ft.parse(dateValue);
```

Depois incremente a data em um dia usando `Calendar`

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(); 
c.setTime(date); 
c.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
```

E logo após, recupere a data e salve no seu objeto

```
date = c.getTime();
```

Juntando tudo

```
 String dateValue = seuEditText.getText().
   .toString()
   .trim();

SimpleDateFormat ft = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
Date date = ft.parse(dateValue);
 Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(); 
          c.setTime(date); 
          c.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
date = c.getTime();
```

EDIT: para mostrar a nova data, faça o seguinte

```
String strDate = ft.formart(date);
Toast.makeText(this, "A nova data de entrega é em " + strDate, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
  .show();
```

É importante que o valor do seu `EditText` esteja no formato `dd/MM/yyyy`. Espero que funcione!

Comment: Essa parte onde eu pego minha data lançada no EditText não ficou bem clara para mim, poderia explicar?

Comment: Pronto @user3873165, adicionei uma edição à minha resposta pra deixar claro como fazer isso

Comment: certo, agora compreendi melhor, vou tentar adaptar, mas vejo que seria necessário um novo EditText  para manipular os dados de forma transparente e entregar a data final somente no banco e também em um mensageiro estilo toast, pois caso o usuário não faça nada não haverá transformações nesses elementos.

Comment: Se entendi bem, você não precisa de outro `EditText`. É só usar o que você já tem

Comment: mas eu não vou carregar essa nova data nele, somente após a nova consulta do banco de dados, no entanto quero mostrar em uma mensagem estilo Toast.
        'Toast.makeText(ListarEmprestimosActivity.this, "Livro Renovado com Sucesso!\n A nova data renovada será: " date.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();'

Comment: Editei novamente para que seja possível mostra a data como `String`

Comment: Realizando alguns testes consegui imprimir o valor esperado em um editText, mas após sucessivos testes ele deu um erro:
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'long java.util.Date.getTime()' on a null object reference
Isso deve se ao Date date = null; quando ele circunda o parse com try catch?

Comment: Provavelmente, você deve enter porque desse comportamento tá acontecendo